# Not able to add document in MongoDb through Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm new with node and mongodb, i've tried to connect and insert a document in mongodb but I have an error.

```
Failed to insert item: MongoError: Topology is closed, please connect
```

Here is my code

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const uri = "mongodb+srv://user:mypassword@cluster0-h7x26.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useUnifiedTopology: true });
var obj = {name : "test test"};
client.connect(err => {
  const userCollection = client.db("dbtest").collection("users");
  userCollection.insertOne(obj)
  .then(result => console.log(`Successfully inserted item with _id: ${result.insertedId}`))
  .catch(err => console.error(`Failed to insert item: ${err}`))

  client.close();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your DB connection is getting closed even before your DB operation is being done, Your code execution doesn't wait until `userCollection.insertOne(obj)` is executed & it's getting passed to `client.close();` which eventually closing connection, So you need to use `client.close()` inside of `.then()` or `.catch()` which is meant to say once operation is successful or failure it doesn't matter but once you get DB response then close the connection. Please check below :

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const uri = "mongodb+srv://user:mypassword@cluster0-h7x26.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useUnifiedTopology: true });
var obj = { name: "test test" };
client.connect(err => {
    if (err) {  console.log('DB connection err ::',err) // Need to return here. } 
        const userCollection = client.db("dbtest").collection("users");
    userCollection.insertOne(obj)
        .then(result => console.log(`Successfully inserted item with _id: ${result.insertedId}`, client.close()))
        .catch(err => console.error(`Failed to insert item: ${err}`, client.close()))
});
```

Comment: Using `.finally()` sounds like the most relevant thing to do. In either situation the database connection should be closed.

Comment: @JakeHolzinger : Yes can be used, this is a sample I've written just to let OP know what was the issue, Also we don't have this type of connection creation & closure in real-time right.. :-)

Comment: You certainly did point out the issue, I was just adding additional information that might be helpful to other users. Not every node program is a long running server process, there are use-cases for opening and closing a connection when the operation completes.